# Chanage Xml In Dataset

Tags: asp.net, xml, dataset

I'm using asp.net c# framework 4.0.
I have an xml file which I would like to load into a dataset (or in a different way), let the user change values and save the xml.
Is it possible? does anyone have an example?
Thanks.

My xml looks like this:

```
<thumbnail filename="Mustang.jpg" url="http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_069_stationery" target="_blank" 
    title="1999 Red Cupe mustang" 
    description="Very nice mustang" />
<thumbnail filename="Mustang2.jpg" url="http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_069_stationery" target="_blank" 
    title="1999 Red Cupe mustang" 
    description="Very nice mustang 2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `DataSet`, `DOM` and `Linq-to-Xml` API to read/write/update XML document. Use DataSet.ReadXml() and DataSet.WriteXml() methods to read and write Xml document respectively.